# pandas: identifying if a first n characters are letter followed by numbers

Tags: python, pandas, string, contains

I have a dataframe with column which contains multiple reference values. I am trying to filter a ceratin group of references which follow this format:

**ABCD12345678**

Basically the first 4 characters are letters followed by 8 numbers.

I tried:

```
df_new=df[df['col'].str.match('[a-zA-Z]', na = False)]
```

and

```
bew_2=df[df['col'].str.slice(0,4).str.contains('[a2-3]', na = False)]
```

But neither worked. It would be great if someone could guide me through this.

Comment: You might want to use `r'[a-zA-Z]{4}'` (or `r'[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{8}'`) as regex

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```py
m = df['col'].str.match('^\w+\d+$', na = False)

# if the number is fixed

m = df['col'].str.match('^\w{4}\d{8}$', na = False)
```

```
print(m)

0    True
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

Comment: The number is not fixed it is a  random 5 or 6 digit number , preceded by 4 letters

Comment: @tyler Use `'^\w{4}\d+$'`